# Swift Call Particular function from another class for Present ViewController

Tags: swift

My Scenario, I am trying to call a ViewController class file particular function from another one class file. Here, I am getting below warning and `ViewController` not presenting.

My Code Below ViewControllerA

```
func previewview(){ // Inside ViewControllerA

 DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let fileViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "fileviewcontroller")
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: fileViewController)
            self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }  }
```

Below code In Another Class File

```
import UIKit

class FileController {

    //MARK:- Call a file preview
    ViewControllerA().self.previewview()
}
```

> Warning: Attempt to present  on
>    whose view is not in the window
>   hierarchy!

Comment: `ViewControllerA` must be on screen when you're presenting `fileviewcontroller` from it. Also, what is the significance of `ViewControllerA().self`?

Comment: @PGDev which is I mentioned above previewview() that is I placed into ViewControllerA and I have another one class file from that class file I am calling previewview() It is calling but not presenting veiwcontroller

Comment: Using ViewControllerA() you are creating a new instance of your view controller.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. No matter where you've placed you code. The error says, you're presenting `fileviewcontroller` from `ViewControllerA` which is not present currently on the screen. That's why it is not able to present the controller.

Comment: What is the "other class"? You need a way to access the VC that is actually on the screen, not just creating a new `ViewControllerA`.

Comment: @Sweeper I updated my question. Please check it

Comment: @ PGDev is there any solution for this?

Comment: Kindly elaborate the flow that you're trying to implement so I can help.

Comment: @PGDev I am having Textview Text and whenever user click save button I am showing three option like .pdf, .doc and .txt. User can save three different formate based on choosing. Now once file saved I need to show it on preview view with share option. Here, I am maintaining file save functions in separate class and from main class to calling that class file function save operation. Once its done I am calling DocumentIntractionController For Display the file.

Comment: Added the answer. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Viewcontroller().FuncName()
```

Example:

```
LoginViewController().checkLoginValidation()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use swift's Delegate Protocol to call a function in a class from different class.
Here is a link for understanding how delegate protocol works.

https://medium.com/@nimjea/delegation-pattern-in-swift-4-2-f6aca61f4bf5

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can proceed. This is just an example. You can take the idea and implement in you code as per your requirement.

Instead of creating a separate `ViewController`, create a `ViewModel` that handles the implementation of *saving the file*, i.e.

```
class SaveOptionsViewModel {
    func save(file: String, handler: (()->())?) { //add parameters to save a file as per requirement
        //save the file here...
        handler?()
    }
}
```

Now, in the `controller` that contains *multiple save options*, create a property of type `SaveOptionsViewModel`.

And present `PreviewVC` from `SaveOptionsVC` in the `handler` once the file is saved using the `SaveOptionsViewModel` after tapping the `saveButton`.

```
class SaveOptionsVC: UIViewController {
    let viewModel = SaveOptionsViewModel()

    @IBAction func onTapSaveButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.viewModel.save(file: "") {
            if let previewVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PreviewVC") {
                self.present(previewVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add the custom implementation of `PreviewVC` as per your requirement.

```
class PreviewVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    //add the code...
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue that you’re facing?